# Why does my custom target not support the `bin` crate type?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using the custom target file defined in [this](http://www.randomhacks.net/2015/11/11/bare-metal-rust-custom-target-kernel-space/) blog post. It works perfectly fine when building static libraries, however when I try to build a binary instead I get the following warning:

```
warning: dropping unsupported crate type `bin` for target `x86_64-unknown-none-gnu`
```

No binaries are built.

How do I add support for building executables to my target?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because I'm not sure if it's correct, but isn't it because it doesn't make sense to build an executable for a `none` platform? There's no operating system at that level to load the executable into memory and jump to its entry point.

Comment: I tried setting the "os" key to "foo", the "target" key to "x86_64-unknown-foo", and the target file name to "x86_64-unknown-foo.json". No change.

Comment: What is your overall goal?  Are you trying to launch an OS written in Rust?

Comment: I'm writing a unikernel for Xen (i.e. using Xen as a microkernel), my target name should actually be "x86_64-unknown-xen".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this entry to the `$(target).json` file fixes it:

```
"executables": true
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Austin B, you're going to run into some problems when building for the `none` target, or any custom target.  You can check out my [blog posts](http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~tbelaire/blog/posts/gba-rust-1.html) where you see me building for the gba.

What I've been doing is

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn main(_: i32, _: *const *const i8) -> i32 {
    let mut m = gfx::Mode3::new();
    m.dot(120, 80, Color::rgb15(31, 0, 0));
    m.dot(136, 80, Color::rgb15(0, 31, 0));
    m.dot(120, 96, Color::rgb15(0, 0, 31));

    loop{}
}
```

where I declare a `main` function with a C signature, then the platform specific `crt.s` files will load the binary and call main for me.

Then I continue to build as a static lib.